# I am trying to align text and image right next to each other horizontally but the part the image always gets out of span

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, html-tag-details

I am trying to put image at right of the text but it always get cropped out of the container
html/css is:

```css
body {
  background-color: #1e4bdd;
  background: linear-gradient(105deg, #f2eeee, #0808d4);
}

.container {
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 01.5em 1.8em;
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: 100em;
  position: relative;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  background: linear-gradient(55deg, #940ce9, #a88bc9);
}

.image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: #1e4bdd;
  float: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="seacrh">
  <h2> Meal app by Garvit <img class="image" src="heading.jpg" width="150" height="150"></h2>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Type A NOM NOM Dish.." class="inputBox" />
  <button class="inputBtn">Search</button>
</div>
```

[image]

So basically, it gets cropped out of the container. i don't understand why. I tried floating too, but it did not work.

Comment: Seems like the container is the problem, not sure what you were trying to achieve using the transform and the top/left 50%. Remove those, and the image is not going to be cropped.
 Also, center is not a valid value for float

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can replace your code with this. And it should work. I have included two css classes `header-titles` & `header-image`

```
<div class="seacrh">
    <h2 class="header-titles"> Meal app by Garvit </h2>
    <img class="header-image" src = "heading.jpg" width="150" height="150">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type A NOM NOM Dish.." class="inputBox"/>
    <button class="inputBtn">Search</button>
</div>
```

And here are those two css classes.

```
.header-titles{
  width:50%;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}
.header-image{
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: the header image will be stretched to 50% width. Also, text-align affects the alignment of the content and an img tag cannot have content.  
 This will definitely not work as OP expects

Answer (score 0):

The HTML and CSS that you provided don't match. You have `<div class="seacrh">` and `.container {}`. I am going to assume that this should be the same class name and I'll use the correct spelling of "search".

As already commented, the cropping is due to the positioning declarations. This is how it looks without that:

```css
body {
  background-color: #1e4bdd;
  background: linear-gradient(105deg, #f2eeee, #0808d4);
}

.search {
  text-align: justify;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 01.5em 1.8em;
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: 100em;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  /* left: 50%; */
  /* top: 50%; */
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  background: linear-gradient(55deg, #940ce9, #a88bc9);
}

.image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: #1e4bdd;
  /* float: center; */
}
```

```html
<div class="search">
  <h2> Meal app by Garvit <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/150" width="150" height="150"></h2>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Type A NOM NOM Dish.." class="inputBox" />
  <button class="inputBtn">Search</button>
</div>
```

This example suggests using flexbox to position the image next to the heading and search box. By nesting the header and search box in a `div`, that `div` and the image can be positioned side-by-side.

```css
body {
  background-color: #1e4bdd;
  background: linear-gradient(105deg, #f2eeee, #0808d4);
}

.seacrh {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  /* text-align: justify; */
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 01.5em 1.8em;
  width: 90vw;
  max-width: 100em;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
  /* left: 50%; */
  /* top: 50%; */
  border-radius: 0.6em;
  background: linear-gradient(55deg, #940ce9, #a88bc9);
}

.image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: #1e4bdd;
  /* float: center; */
}
```

```html
<div class="seacrh">
  <div>
    <h2> Meal app by Garvit</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Type A NOM NOM Dish.." class="inputBox" />
    <button class="inputBtn">Search</button>
  </div>
  <img class="image" src="//picsum.photos/150" width="150" height="150">
</div>
```